# How can you make a color PDF file when saving a file?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I have a site, and the background color is yellow. When I save this as a [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file, the background color becomes white.

Is it possible, to also save the background color?

Comment: Which application do you use?

Comment: @whitequark: pdf creator and i also have adobe pdf

Comment: Which web browser?

Comment: @variant:firefox & sometimes IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably printing from your browser and I think you should configure that in it, as they often don't print background picture and images, in order to save ink.

For instance (the labels may differ, my applications are in french, moderators are welcome to correct them) :

- Firefox : `File -> Print preview...`, click the `Page layout..` button (2nd button, next to `Print...`, check `Print background`
- IE 7 : `Tools -> Internet options...`, go to the `Advanced` tab, find the `Current printing` section and check `Print background colors and background images`.